# Multer unexpected field error handling

Tags: node.js, multer, multer-s3

The route with my multer middleware goes something like this.

```
router.post('my-route-path', multer.single('file'), controllerFunc)
```

The multer function I have defined is to allow a single file uploaded to the file system. Everything works fine, the issue is if I have define the field name to be `file` If in my client request I set the field name to be `file` it works great. But if I give it `xyz` then it throws an error. Which it should the problem is I can't seem to catch that error, in my `catch(e)` block of my promise.

This is the error I get

```
Error: Unexpected field
at makeError (F:\Servup\chat\node_modules\multer\lib\make-error.js:12:13)
at wrappedFileFilter (F:\Servup\chat\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
at Busboy.<anonymous> (F:\Servup\chat\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
at emitMany (events.js:146:13)
at Busboy.emit (events.js:223:7)
at Busboy.emit (F:\Servup\chat\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
at PartStream.<anonymous> (F:\Servup\chat\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at PartStream.emit (events.js:210:7)
at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (F:\Servup\chat\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:210:7)
at HeaderParser._finish (F:\Servup\chat\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
at SBMH.<anonymous> (F:\Servup\chat\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at SBMH.emit (events.js:210:7)
```

The current implementation that I tried in my `catch` block was this. (this doesn't work)

```
catch(e => {
    if (e === 'Unexpected field') {
       // catch that error here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch an unexpected field error by doing this

url: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

```
var upload = multer().single('avatar')

app.post('/profile', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // An error occurred when uploading
      return
    }

    // Everything went fine
  })
})
```